# Only use And operator if a value aren't empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query, how do i make the last And operator `And um_languages.meta_value LIKE %s` only used if `um_languages.meta_value` aren't empty.
Thanks

```
SELECT
    u.ID          
FROM
    wp_users u            
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta um_key_practice          ON um_key_practice.user_id = u.id           AND um_key_practice.meta_key            = 'key_practice'
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta um_languages             ON um_languages.user_id = u.id              AND um_languages.meta_key               = 'languages'         
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta um_profile_type          ON um_profile_type.user_id  = u.id          AND um_profile_type.meta_key            = 'lawyer_profile_type'
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta um_searchable            ON um_searchable.user_id  = u.id            AND um_searchable.meta_key              = 'lawyer_is_searchable'
WHERE
    um_profile_type.meta_value = 'extended' AND 
    um_searchable.meta_value = '1' AND                               

    (
        um_key_practice.meta_value = %s
        OR
        um_key_practice.meta_value = %s
            
    ) AND

         um_languages.meta_value LIKE %s AND
```

Comment: what does empty mean?  the empty string?  null?  either?

Comment: Empty as if its null

Comment: `(um_languages.meta_value is null or um_languages.meta_value like %s)`

Comment: NULL & EMPTY might not be the same, I would rather rephrase the clause as;

... um_languages.meta_value IS NOT NULL 
AND um_languages.meta_value > '' 
AND um_languages.meta_value LIKE '%s'

Answer (score 0):

if your column is already null , like operator will ignore nulls and doesn't return that row.
also you need to pass %s as string

```
... 
AND um_languages.meta_value LIKE '%s'
```

but if you want to return null values:

```
...
AND ( um_languages.meta_value LIKE '%s' or um_languages.meta_value is null)
```